# How to use enum in iOS 8 Swift framework public API

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I'm trying to create a Swift framework usable by other iOS 8 apps using Swift or Objective C.

In a few of my public functions, I required the use of an enum. Of course, Swift has enums, but these are not compatible with client apps using Objective C. So then I tried to use an Objective C style enum of the form:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyEnumType)
{
    MyEnumTypeGreen,
    MyEnumTypeBlue,
    MyEnumTypeYellow
};
```

To make this enum type public, I put this declaration in a PublicEnums.h. To access from my Swift code I need this line in my framework project's Bridging-Header.h:

```
#import "PublicEnums.h"
```

But then I get a this error:

> Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'MyFramework' which flags a line in the auto-generated MyFramework-Swift.h file:

```
#import "/Users/sourcepath.../ObjectiveC/MyFramework-Bridging-Header.h"
```

Is there really no way to use any kind of enum in a Swift framework that is usable from an Objective C app?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this in a new project and everything works fine. I think your error is due to not using the bridging header correctly.

I think you should not import the bridging header with an import statement. It should be automatically added to your target's Build Settings under the bridging header key:

```
Objective-C Bridging Header ------     projectName/projectName-Bridging-Header.h
```

The raw name of this key is `SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER`.

The test:

```
    let x = MyEnumType.Blue
    println("\(x.toRaw())") // 1
```

*Note that in Xcode 6.1 the last line would use `rawValue`.*

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not #importing the bridging header; it's actually set at the project level as you described. The error occurs because the auto-generated MyFramework-Swift.h automatically includes that #import statement. I think to reproduce you need a single workspace with both a Swift framework and a sample app referencing the framework.

Comment: If you have an incompatible framework ask the maintainer to update it.

Comment: Hmm, I guess you have to update it yourself then, right? Remove the include statement!

Comment: Like I said, the MyFramework-Swift.h file is automatically generated. This happens in the consuming application at build time. I can't remove the line.

Comment: It seems that there is a difference between importing Swift into Objective-C or *vice versa*. In this case you want to import Objective-C into Swift, and the above describes how it is done. The "MyFramework-Swift.h" file is used for importing Swift into Objective-C. I think it can easily be avoided to mix both at the same time.